# How to define an empty, "uninitialized" keypath and set it later?

Tags: swift, keypaths

I made a program to calculate the total width/height of views (sometimes I want the total width, sometimes I want the total height). The only catch is: If I'm calculating the width, I want to add an extra `10` to the total. Here's my current code:

```
func calculateLengthOfAllViews(calculatingWidth: Bool) {
    let views = [
        UIView(frame: CGRect.zero),
        UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50)),
        UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 50))
    ]

    var totalLength: CGFloat = 0
    
    if calculatingWidth {
        totalLength += 10 /// add extra 10 if calculating width
    } else {
        totalLength += 0
    }
    
    for view in views { /// add each view's width/height
        let length: CGFloat
        if calculatingWidth {
            length = view.frame.width
        } else {
            length = view.frame.height
        }
        totalLength += length
    }
    
    print("Total length is \(totalLength)")
}

calculateLengthOfAllViews(calculatingWidth: true) /// Total length is 160.0
calculateLengthOfAllViews(calculatingWidth: false) /// Total length is 100.0
```

This works fine. But, I'm repeating `if calculatingWidth {` in 2 places, to determine:

1. Whether to add extra padding 10 padding
2. Whether to use `view.frame.width` or `view.frame.height` as the length

The second if-statement is unnecessary, because it always evaluates to the same thing in every iteration.

So, I think [keypaths](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/language/what-are-keypaths) are the way to go -- I can store a reference to either `.width` or `.height` from the first if-statement. However, how do I define a keypath without "initializing" it? I would like to do something like this:

```
let keyPath: KeyPath /// Reference to generic type 'KeyPath' requires arguments in <...>

if calculatingWidth {
    totalLength += 10
    keyPath = \UIView.frame.width
} else {
    totalLength += 0
    keyPath = \UIView.frame.height
}

for view in views {
    let length = view[keyPath: keyPath] /// Type of expression is ambiguous without more context
    totalLength += length
}
```

However, this gives me `Reference to generic type 'KeyPath' requires arguments in <...>`. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
class KeyPath<Root, Value>
```

is a generic type with two type parameters: the root type and the result value type, and those must be specified in the declaration of the variable. In your case it would be

```
let keyPath: KeyPath<UIView, CGFloat>
```

With that definition, the remaining code compiles as well.

Answer (score 4):

You are using `if` at the start of the function, and `if` on *every* iteration of the loop. I think a better way to do this would be to use [`reduce(into:_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/3126956-reduce), to reduce the number of conditional branches.

Code:

```
func calculateLengthOfAllViews(calculatingWidth: Bool) {
    let views = [
        UIView(frame: CGRect.zero),
        UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50)),
        UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 50))
    ]

    let totalLength: CGFloat

    if calculatingWidth {
        totalLength = views.reduce(10, { $0 + $1.frame.width })
    } else {
        totalLength = views.reduce(0, { $0 + $1.frame.height })
    }

    print("Total length is \(totalLength)")
}
```

Comment: Thanks! In my real code I have some more stuff besides `$0 += $1.frame.width`, so I'm going to go with [Martin R's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68795130/14351818) for now.

Comment: Just a remark: `reduce(into:_:)` is efficient when the result is a copy-on-write type, e.g. an array. With trivial types like numbers one can also do `views.reduce(10) { $0 + $1.frame.width }` .